# how to start an app automatically whenever my blackberry will switch on

Tags: blackberry, background

I've completed a tracking system project in my blackberry 8520.

- After I deploy my app to my mobile the application should start automatically and I should be able to switch to that application whenever I want.
- When the application is in the background it should not terminate when I press the back button.  Instead it should again go to background. It should close only when clicking the close option in the menu.

Are these possible? If yes please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project Folder in eclipse.
Then open `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml`
and then check the `Auto-run on startup` and save it.

This will run the application when you restart the phone.

Comment: Ok. That answered my first question. Can you tell me the solution for my second question

Comment: i could not understand second question would you explain me.

Comment: When i press back button when i am in the application it should not terminate. It should be added to the background

Comment: ok then write..
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int status) {
 if(keycode==1769472)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
 }

Comment: using such keycodes is not recommended practice. If you don't want the application to exit upon selecting BACK button, you will need to just override close() method (you don't need to do anything in close method)